# Am I able to use recordID.recordName in a CKQuery?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckquery, ckrecord

`CKQuery` doc says: *Key names used in predicates correspond to fields in the currently evaluated record. Key names may include the names of the record’s metadata properties **such as "creationDate”** or any data fields you added to the record.*

What else metadata can I use in a `CKQuery`? Am I able to use `record.recordID.recordName`, if yes, what is the `key` for it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you could create a CKQuery for searching a recordID like this:

```
var query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "creatorUserRecordID" ,CKReference(recordID: theSearchRecordId, action: CKReferenceAction.None)))
```

Where theSearchRecordId is the recordID.recordName that you are looking for

Metadata fields are recordID, recordType, creationDate, creatorUserRecordID, modificationDate, lastModifiedUserRecordID, recordChangeTag

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014044-CH1-SW14

Comment: holy macaroni it works, I was looking for this more then a months, expression for my case: `let pr = NSPredicate(format: "recordID = %@", CKRecordID(recordName: theSearchRecordId))`

Comment: I had to add a `Queryable` index on the `createdBy` field in the CloudKit dashboard before it would let me query (it kept giving me an .invalidArguments error), but after that it worked.

Comment: for me, with Swift 5.1, `let pr = NSPredicate(format: "recordID = %@", CKRecord.ID(recordName: theSearchRecordId))`

Answer (score 0):

I like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
      @"recordID = %@",[[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:theRecordNameForThisRecord]];
```